# In Julia, can a macro access the inferred type of its arguments?

Tags: julia

In Julia, is there a way to write a macro that branches based on the (compile-time) type of its arguments, at least for arguments whose types can be inferred at compile time? Like, in the example below, I made up a function named `code_type` that returns the compile-time type of `x`. Is there any function like that, or any way to produce this kind of behavior? (Or do macros get expanded before types are inferred, such that this kind of thing is impossible.)

```
macro report_int(x)
  code_type(x) == Int64 ? "it's an int" : "not an int"
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Macros cannot do this, but generated functions can.

Check out the docs here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#Generated-functions-1

Comment: Just a minor pedantic note: generated functions operate on the actual types of its arguments and not just the inferred types.  (The two are the same if the function is type-stable).

Comment: Good point. I should also mention this is only available on recent 0.4dev builds.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to spencerlyon2's answer, another option is to just generate explicit branches:

```
macro report_int(x)
    :(isa(x,Int64) ? "it's an int" : "not an int")
end
```

If `@report_int(x)` is used inside a function, and the type of `x` can be inferred, then the JIT will be able to optimise away the dead branch (this approach is used by the [`@evalpoly` macro](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/78b4dfa741ecccff797c184058e7550a5ee28868/base/math.jl#L83) in the standard library).